# Delaying React Router Link transition to add custom animation component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a project where I need a page transition animation to happen and cannot seem to find a way of delaying React Router's Link component from immediately changing the page. The beginning of the animation shifts a grid over that page to cover, then once the page is loaded the selected page should show.

The way this is being done currently is through setting isLoading to true on a Link click then setting isLoading to false when the next component has mounted. This works fine except for the current page does not stay on-screen during the initial screen cover.

```
class tests extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            isDoneLoading: false,
        };
    }

    changeIsLoading = (newVal) => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: newVal });
    };

    changeIsDoneLoading = (newVal) => {
        this.setState({ isDoneLoading: newVal });
    };

    navLoading = () => {
        this.setState({ isDoneLoading: false, isLoading: true });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='test'>
                <Navbar navLoading={this.navLoading} />
                {!this.state.isDoneLoading && (
                    <LoadingScreen
                        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                        isDoneLoading={this.state.isDoneLoading}
                        changeIsDoneLoading={this.changeIsDoneLoading}
                    />
                )}
                <Route
                    render={({ location }) => (
                        <Switch>
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path='/page1'
                                render={(routeProps) => (
                                    <Page1
                                        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                                        changeIsLoading={this.changeIsLoading}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path='/page2'
                                render={(routeProps) => (
                                    <Page2
                                        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                                        changeLoading={this.changeLoading}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        </Switch>
                    )}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Rough code so sorry about that!

Is there a way of delaying the route from appearing before the next page is already loaded? I cannot seem to find a clean way of doing this and would appreciate any assistance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trying to handle this on your own could get a bit messy. Have you considered using the framer-motion package? It's a widely used and simple solution for things like this. I currently use it in quite a few apps and it works wonders. Handles all the mounting/unmounting animations for you, including route changes.

Comment: @Chris Does framer-motion have a way to delaying this animation? I was planning on checking framer out after this project, but if it helps with animations like this I might just jump right in.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to framer so I'm not sure of all the capabilities, but it is pretty powerful in general. The only sort of "delay" i've seen so far is a delay for how many seconds you want the animation to wait before starting. There are all sorts of event methods and what not that you can tie in to as well.

Comment: @Chris I'll check it out for this I appreciate the help!